# Property leakDetectionThreshold does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp

I am trying to use this property but it gives me that exception, I tried even with: pgjdbc-ng | com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource but without success, it gives me tha same title exception.

```
ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf - Property leakDetectionThreshold  does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource

java.lang.RuntimeException: Property leakDetectionThreshold  does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
```

HirakriCP configuration:

```
    ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", serverAddress);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", database);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", port);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("leakDetectionThreshold ", 5000);
```

and alternatively:

```
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("host", serverAddress);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("database", database);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("port", port);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
```

May I be doing something wrong? I am scared that I couldn't find anyone with the same problem over the internet oO

Than you in advance,
Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

leakDetectionThreshold is not a driver property we need set this datasource property like this:

```
    ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setLeakDetectionThreshold(5000);
```